# Clip the 1st widget with ellipsis (on overflow) in a Row of 3 Text widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Row of 3 text widgets. I want the first two to stay together and the third one to be aligned at the end of the row. The first text has the potential to cause an overflow, and when that happens, I only want the first text to be clipped by an ellipsis. Note that the 2nd and 3rd text can vary in length too, so the width at which clipping should be done varies.

I have tried various things, with `RichText`, `Spacer`, `Expanded`, `Flexible`, etc. The closest I have come to a solution is with this:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
          "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      "Xyz",
      style: customStyle1,
    ),
    Text(
      " 10:20",
      style: customStyle2,
    ),
  ],
),
```

This is what it leads to (with added colors). If the time stays to the right in the first row, the problem will be solved.

[image]

Adding a spacer between the last two texts causes the first to occupy just half the screen, i.e., the ellipsis gets added prematurely. Adding an Expanded to last Text causes the

> "NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE" bug.

The first and the last row in this image are the desired outputs.

[image]

How do I accomplish this? And can anyone explain the issue with using a `Spacer` or an `Expanded` as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use two rows to align items, `Flexible` and Text `softWrap` to fix the overflow

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          Flexible(
            child: Text(
              "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              softWrap: false,
            ),
          ),
          Text("Xyz"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      " 10:20",
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works. Thanks. I guess the `overflow` and `softWrap` properties in the 3rd text were added by mistake, right?

Comment: oh yes, thanks, I was testing, it will work though, let me update it,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constrained box

```
Row(
 children: [
 ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  ),
   child: const Text(
     "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   ),
 ),
 const Text('xyz'),
 const Spacer(),
 const Text('10:20'),
 ],
),
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for my problem. I do not want to limit the first text to half the width.

Comment: No Problem, understood

Answer (score 0):

```
///you can use SizedBox and assign width and you can set your text. This is not the perfect solution but this works for me. 
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class MyAseet extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyAseet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _MyAseetState createState() => _MyAseetState();
    }
    
    class _MyAseetState extends State<MyAseet> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0,top: 50),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      child: Text(
                        "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Xyz",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text(
                        " 10:20",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 200,
                      child: Text(
                        "Left most text that overflows the screen and creates an ellipsis",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Xyz",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Text(
                        " 10:20",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for my problem. The width at which clipping should be done is not known in advance, as the 2nd and 3rd text can vary in length too.